# Markdown/Github: syntax highlighting of code block as a child of a list

Tags: github, markdown

In Github/MD, if we want to enable code block when it is a child of list, we need to intent it by 8 spaces.

But how to make that code block has the syntax highlighting feature?

The following code does not work as expected...

````
    1. foo

             ```python
                print 'bar'
             ```

    2. bar
````

Answer (score 20, accepted):

````
```python
print 'bar'
```
````

without spaces should work: from [GitHub help page](http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/):

> Just wrap your code blocks in ``` and **you won't need to indent manually to trigger a code block**.

---

As illustrated in [hilz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1385800/hilz)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19328233/6309) below, you need to indent the ```` with the same indentation level + 2 spaces than your list.
**The content of the code block doesn't need to be indented**.

`````
1. foo

  ````python
print 'bar'
  ````

  1.

    ````python
print 'bar'
    ````
`````

See [this gist as an example](https://gist.github.com/VonC/10666727):

[image: indented code block]

Comment: What I mean is they are inside a list, see my updated code. Thanks.

Comment: @Howard: list and pre-formatted code don't mixed together well. I prefer making the list manually in order to be sure pre-formatted code will be rendered correctly.

Comment: @VonC: What do you mean my ‘making the list manually’? Using the Markdown slash-dot escape syntax?

Comment: @DanielGasienica no, using `1/`, and `2/` (which aren't interpreted as a list) instead of `1.` and `2.`. Since they aren't interpreted as list, you would then have to make that list manually (ie you would increment yourself the index of each point within that manual list)

Comment: I tried this but my syntax highligted code block indentation doesn't follow the list it is in. @Howard did you really successfully use ``` to indent syntax highlighted code block in the middle of a list?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work anymore in the tracker - indending by 8 spaces works but it's less handy obviously

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Strange... the gist is still rendered properly: https://gist.github.com/VonC/10666727

Comment: Strange indeed - copy pasting in an issue it messes up - maybe different rules for issues ?

Answer (score 11):

To get code blocks with syntax highlighting embedded happily in a list, embed the markup lines that come before and after the code block to the appropriate level of indenting for an additional paragraph, then proceed as normal. For example:

````
1. lorem ipsum

  ```ruby
resources :dolor
  ```

   1. sit amet

      ```ruby
resources :elit
      ```

   1. sed do

1. eiusmod
````

indents each code block to the appropriate depth and maintains the integrity of the indexes.

Comment: This works. I just had to indent the whole block with 2 spaces to make the code block part of the list item. I think this answers the question better than the accepted answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it actually solves the problem in the OP, that of a syntax-highlighted code block **within a list**.

Comment: This is not working any longer.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, you have to do the following:

````
1. lorem ipsum
  ```perl
  use strict;
  ```
2. dolor sit amet
      ```perl
      use warnings;
      ```
   1. consectetur adipiscing elit
   1. sed do
1. eiusmod
````

That is, make sure your syntax-highlighted code starts in the same column as the backticks.  You also have to help the numbering out a little bit, because it appears to lose count after code blocks.

See also: https://gist.github.com/therealbstern/9cb0dfc7f0f4b76a062247676aed341b

Comment: Shiki pointed this out in a comment above, under hilz's answer, but I needed to put this in an answer, because having the correct answer buried in a comment didn't seem clear enough.  Also, comments don't allow full markdown, which is needed to make it abundantly clear.